# Canvas - Drawing second line to erase first one

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, I have one line that bounce from walls of my border while changing colours. But now I must create the second, white line, that will go like 3 or 4 seconds after first line erasing it. So it will be only 4 second lenght colour line bouncing from walls. And I have no idea how to do it. I already tried to use setTimeout, creating multiple functions etc.

```js
     var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.lineWidth=1;


var x=0
var y=0
var dx=1
var dy=1



function rysuj(){
    ctx.strokeStyle="#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+dx,y+dy);
    ctx.stroke();
    if(x>200||x<0) dx=-dx;
    if(y>150||y<0) dy=-dy;
    x=x+dx;
    y=y+dy; 
}
setInterval ('rysuj()', 5);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" style="width:1000px; height:500px; border-style:solid;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: First, do this `var rysuj = function() { // ... function code here };` and then do `setInterval(rysuj, 5)`

Comment: So after that I must create second var function, but this time with ctx.strokeStyle="white"  ? Then it do just some dots but no clear colour line, and white line after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the key is to have two draw functions (note, this isn't ideal, but it works) and always have the "white" function explicitly set the strokeStyle. This is because the context for both draw functions is retrieved from the same canvas, and unless you explicitly set it on the "white" draw, it will be whatever it was from the previous "red" draw.

See below:

```
var getCanvasContext = function(strokeColor) {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
      ctx.strokeStyle=strokeColor;
      ctx.lineWidth=1;
      return {ctx: ctx, x: 0, y:0, dx:1, dy:1, change: strokeColor !== "white"};
    }

    var drawRed = function(canvasContext) {
      var ctx = canvasContext.ctx,
          x = canvasContext.x,
          y = canvasContext.y,
          dx = canvasContext.dx,
          dy = canvasContext.dy;

      if (canvasContext.change) {
        ctx.strokeStyle="#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x,y);
      ctx.lineTo(x+dx, y+dy);
      ctx.stroke();
      if(x>200||x<0) dx=-dx;
      if(y>150||y<0) dy=-dy;
      x=x+dx;
      y=y+dy;

      canvasContext.ctx = ctx;
      canvasContext.x = x;
      canvasContext.y = y;
      canvasContext.dx = dx;
      canvasContext.dy = dy;
    };

    var drawWhite = function(canvasContext) {
        var ctx = canvasContext.ctx,
            x = canvasContext.x,
            y = canvasContext.y,
            dx = canvasContext.dx,
            dy = canvasContext.dy;

        ctx.strokeStyle="#ffffff";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x+dx, y+dy);
        ctx.stroke();
        if(x>200||x<0) dx=-dx;
        if(y>150||y<0) dy=-dy;
        x=x+dx;
        y=y+dy;

        canvasContext.ctx = ctx;
        canvasContext.x = x;
        canvasContext.y = y;
        canvasContext.dx = dx;
        canvasContext.dy = dy;
    };

    var redContext = getCanvasContext("red");
    var whiteContext = getCanvasContext("white");

    setInterval(function() {
      drawRed(redContext);
    }, 5);

    setTimeout(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        drawWhite(whiteContext)
      }, 5);
    }, 4000);
```

Hopefully this helps (see fiddle: [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6n4ky0fs/))